# strtok_s security debugging warnings solving

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a piece of code which has been complied by Dev C++ correctly. When I tried to execute it using VS2012 express I faced this warning ''warning C4996: '': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strtok_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details''

I tried to disable security warnings, but I found _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS option is not available in my VS express. so I had to modify my code to use strtok_s instead of strtok to avoid this warning. However, even the code executes to the end without any errors, something went wrong that the results do not appear. obviously no reading files occur. This is the previous code which worked well on Dev C++

```
const char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0
    // parse the line
    token[0] = strtok(buf, DELIMITER); // first token
    if (token[0]) // zero if line is blank
    {
      for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
      {
    token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITER); // subsequent tokens
        if (!token[n]) break; // no more tokens
```

and this is what I tried to execute using VS2012 express

```
const char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0
    char* next_token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0
    //char* next_token;
    // parse the line
    token[0] = strtok_s(buf, DELIMITER, &next_token[0]); // first token
    if (token[0]) // zero if line is blank
    {
      for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
      {
    token[n] = strtok_s(0, DELIMITER, &next_token[n]); // subsequent tokens
        if (!token[n]) break; // no more tokens
```

What is wrong with the second code?

Comment: `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` certainly is available. You just have to know it's a macro which you must define before the first Microsoft header is included. There's no nice checkbox in any Visual Studio version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the next consecutive call to `strtok_s` expects the `context` pointer (the last argument to `strtok_s`) to filled in by the last call.

You use a different (uninitialized) pointer each call, which means that the context is lost, or rather that it uses a seemingly random pointer as the context.

You should use the outcommented variable `next_token` instead of the array.

Comment: I did use the outcommented variable next_token and it works fine. the other choice I found is to set SDL check to be off. Thanks